# Not able to open selector in solaris for non root user

Tags: java, css-selectors, nio

I have a server application which runs fine in most of the cases but in one solaris machine it not able to open the selector ,for root user it is working fine. for other user it is giving the below exception

```
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
at sun.nio.ch.DevPollArrayWrapper.init(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.DevPollArrayWrapper.<init>(DevPollArrayWrapper.java:74)
at sun.nio.ch.DevPollSelectorImpl.<init>(DevPollSelectorImpl.java:54)
     at sun.nio.ch.DevPollSelectorProvider.openSelector(DevPollSelectorProvider.java:18)
at java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Selector.java:209)
```

any suggestions on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the absence of a more comprehensive error message from the native wrapper, use [`truss`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1461/truss-1.html#scrolltoc) to identify the low-level system call which fails (most probably with `EACCES`), while running as the non-`root` user:

```
truss -l -d -f -vall -wall -o truss.out java ... TestOrAppClass
```

What you expect to see in `truss.out` after the Java application throws the exception and terminates (or is terminated) -- note the interleaved spaces in `I O E x c e p t i o n`:

```
...
...
...
...
23515/1:         0.2912 some_system_call(params)                        Err#13 EACCES [ALL]
...
23515/1:         0.2923 write(2, 0x08044F84, 39)                        = 39
23515/1:           j a v a . i o . I O E x c e p t i o n :   P e r m i s s i o n
23515/1:           d e n i e d
...
...
...
...
```

If the application in question is too complex and generates too much output (or is otherwise difficult to invoke from the command line), then write and compile a small test class which reproduces the problem by calling `java.nio.channels.Selector.open()` directly.

If you do not/cannot write a simple test class then remember that you can always use the extra output logged by the `-wall` option to correlate the time (and thread/LWP) at which the stack trace printout was produced with the actual system call, which should have failed shortly before.

In the sample `truss.out` output above, `23515` is the process ID, `/1` is the LWP ID (doubling as "thread" identifier if the JVM uses native threads, which it almost certainly does on Solaris), `0.2912` is the timestamp (seconds since `java` process/trace startup), and `some_system_call` failing with `EACCES` is the call of interest.

What version of the JDK are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the help.After checking truss i found the problem , for non root user it failed to access /dev/poll ,it is giving the error Err#13 EACCES [ALL] . But u have any idea why it is like this

Comment: Which system call exactly failed?  `ioctl`, `open`?  See http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/816-5177/poll-7d?l=en&a=view for one possible reason (if `/dev/poll` is already open by a parent process before forking -- not sure whether this is applicable to your application...)

Comment: open failed , i tried to open /dev/poll for that user it is not opening